# Is "hang" really short for "hang out"?

Tags: slang, colloquialisms

I saw [this entry](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=hang) in Urban Dictionary (I know, not the best place for formal English, but it does do a pretty good job at collecting slang).

> 1.hang
>
> short for "hang out"
>
> "I'm just gonna hang at Lolita's place today"

My question is, do people really use "hang" for "hang out"? i.e. do people really say "Let's hang some time". I have never heard of people saying it, and it sounds awful to me. It sounds like you want to hang yourself.

Comment: If you Google "hang with", you'll find lots of examples.

Comment: Here's a [BrE example](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22we're+just+hanging+just%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1) showing that speakers can and do casually interleave plain **hanging** with **hanging around** and **hanging about**. Which I think is sufficiently obvious that the question is General Reference.

Comment: Of course slang varies from place to place.  If you have not heard it, maybe it is not current where you are.  Or your perhaps you and friends are the wrong age for that slang.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not only do people use *hang* as a verb, short for "hang out", but it's also fairly common to hear *hang* as a noun - short for "person to hang out with", or "company":

"Let's do this again sometime soon.  You're **a good hang**."

I can only speak for California in this context, but I can attest to its use in many different socio-economic settings - it's always informal, and only between friends, but it's used by all but the oldest and/or most patrician.

Answer (score 7):

You ask if people use it and the answer is "yes." I ask my kid, "Where are you going and what's your plan?" And the kid says "We are just going to hang at **__**."

I have even heard "I'll hang here with you."